# Error in Spring MVC Custom EL Function to Format String

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using Spring and building a web app. I am creating a custom EL Function and I am trying to format a phone number which is a String from 1234567890 to 123-456-7890 output.

I tested the method 'phoneFormat' in a standalone java application and passed a string, ex "3101234567", and it correctly formatted it. When I use it in phones.jsp, I am passing 'phone.number' **Can I pass phones.number the way I did -
${myTags:phoneFormat(phone.number)} ?**

You can see below the files I am working with. **Do you see anything wrong that prevents this from working?** When I load that page, it currently does not display the Phone number at all.

**/StudentWebMVC/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/personal/phones.jsp**
This is a portion of the file where I output the phone number

```
<c:otherwise>
<div>
<%@ taglib prefix="myTags" uri="/WEB-INF/tags/functions.tld" %>
${myTags:phoneFormat(phone.number)} *this is how I am trying to format the phone number to 123-456-7890 output* 
<%-- ${phone.number} --%> *this is how it is currently, it outputs the number to the screen*
</div>
<c:if test="${phone != null && type == 'personal' }">
<div>Send emergency text messages: <spring:message code="studentContact.emergency.notification.${phone.notificationFlag}" /></div>
</c:if>
</c:otherwise>
```

**/StudentWebMVC/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/functions.tld**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <display-name>phoneFormatUtil</display-name>    
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>myPhoneFormat</short-name>
<uri>/StudentWebMVC/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/functions.tld</uri>


    <function>
        <name>phoneFormat</name>
        <function-class>/StudentWebMVC/src/main/java/edu/dt/studentweb/mvc/utils/PhoneFormatUtil.phoneFormat</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String phoneFormat(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

**/StudentWebMVC/src/main/java/edu/dt/studentweb/mvc/utils/PhoneFormatUtil.java**

```
public final class PhoneFormatUtil {
    static String exStr;
    public static java.lang.String phoneFormat(java.lang.String str)  {

        MaskFormatter mf;
        try {
            mf = new MaskFormatter("###-###-####");
            mf.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
            exStr = mf.valueToString(str);
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return exStr;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<function-class>` in your functions.tld seems wrong. Try `<function-class>edu.dt.studentweb.mvc.utils.PhoneFormatUtil</function-class>` .